# PHP soap login auth

Tags: php, soap

Following my code webservice soap:

```
   if (isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"] == "login") {
$soapClient = new SoapClient(WEST_SOAP_WSDL,
    array("trace" => WEST_SOAP_TRACE, "login" => WEST_SOAP_LOGIN, "password" => WEST_SOAP_PASS));

try {
    $clienteId = $soapClient->loginAuth($_POST["username"]);
} catch (Exception $e) {
     print_r($e);
}

if ($clienteId) {
    session_regenerate_id(TRUE);

    $_SESSION["auth"]["id"] = $clienteId;
    $_SESSION["auth"]["username"] = $_POST["username"]; 

    try {
        $_SESSION['cliente'] =   serialize($soapClient->getClientDataById($clienteId));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
     print_r($e);
    }
```

How could I Restrict access to my php in subscriber panel in status below ? :

```
        inactive
        canceled
```

Comment: could u not store a  `status` fields in the session?  then check for that as well if they logged in or not, etc

Comment: explain more please !

Comment: hold on sec `$_SESSION["auth"]["id"]`  , has this already  got the `status` in it? if i am correct.. then u could do something  like `if($_SESSION["auth"]["id"] === "inactive") #do this else #do that`

Comment: if a do this     if ($_SESSION["auth"]["id"] === 'inativo'){
 exit;

           } else {
   require_once 'login.php';
 exit;
}

Comment: nothing happens,,, and i try other ways but not,,,   can you save me more ?

Comment: do get any errors?  try simple `echo` in the `if-else` with no `exit`. to see if your code actual works

Comment: yes it works good,,, but How can I Break the login if the user be inactive ?

Comment: if ($_SESSION["auth"]["id"] === 'inativo'){
echo "inativo";

           } else {
            require_once 'login.php';

Comment: not sure what u mean , but  if your  authentication is based on session,  u can  try unsetting the session `unset($_SESSION["auth"])` .